# Eclipse: Automatic makefile generation not working?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

In the console in the image below, you can see that automatic linking probably isn't working correctly. What do I need to do? Below is the code I'm using. I also did a refresh, clean, and rebuild, but the error remains.

[image]

```
/*
 * Fibonacci.h
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 2, 2014
 *      Author: rose
 */

#ifndef FIBONACCI_H_
#define FIBONACCI_H_


unsigned int Fibonacci(unsigned int n);


#endif /* FIBONACCI_H_ */



/*
 * Fibonacci.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 2, 2014
 *      Author: rose
 */


#include "Fibonacci.h"

unsigned int Fibonacci(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n==1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Fibonacci(n-2) + Fibonacci(n-1);
}



/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 2, 2014
 *      Author: rose
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Fibonacci(10) = " << Fibonacci(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's a compile time error and has nothing to do with your linker settings. Make sure the `Fibonacci.h` is included with `#include`, is the correct file **and** includes the declaration for `Fibonacci`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a linker problem, its the compiler. You need to include `Fibonacci.h` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: I miscopied the code. You can see in the image that this include is indeed present.